# Updating a record in table from a form by using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with data for some vehicles and I use the following code to insert vehicles information in the table and it works good,
now I want to update this code so that I can change the number of any vehicle (MachNO) in the table.
Note: MachNO is the primary key of the tbMachines and it is related to a one-to-many relationship with other tables

````
On Error GoTo Err_btnSave_Click
    
If Nz(Me.txtMachNo, vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Nz(Me.cmbMachGroupID, vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Nz(Me.cmbMachSiteID, vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Nz(Me.cmbMachKmKind, vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "please complete all neccessary fields ", vbCritical, " attention"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If Me.txtMachNo <> MachSelectd Then
        Set RsMach = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbMachines", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        RsMach.AddNew
        RsMach!MachNo = Me.txtMachNo.Value
        RsMach!ID = IIf(IsNull(DMax("[id]", "tbMachines") + 1), 1, DMax("[id]", "tbMachines") + 1)
    Else
        Set RsMach = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbMachines where MachNo = '" & MachSelectd & "'")
        RsMach.edit
    End If
        RsMach!MachNo = Me.txtMachNo.Value
        RsMach!PajNO = Me.txtPajNO.Value
        RsMach!MachType = Me.txtMachType.Value
        RsMach!MachGroupID = Me.cmbMachGroupID.Value
        RsMach!MachChasiNO = Me.txtMachChasiNO.Value
        RsMach!MachSiteID = Me.cmbMachSiteID.Value
        RsMach!MachKmKind = Me.cmbMachKmKind.Value
        RsMach!MachFeatures = Me.txtMachFeatures.Value
        RsMach!MachCountry = Me.txtMachCountry.Value
        RsMach!MachModel = Me.txtMachModel.Value
        RsMach!MachDate = Me.txtMachDate.Value
        RsMach!Clarefication = Me.txtClarefiction.Value
      
        RsMach.Update
        Form_frmMachinesSub.Requery
        RsMach.Close
    MsgBox " done  "
    clearForm
    btnNew.Enabled = True
    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnCancel.Enabled = False
    
End If

Exit_btnSave_Click:
    Exit Sub
    
Err_btnSave_Click:
    MsgBox err.Description
    Resume Exit_btnSave_Click
End Sub```
````

Comment: Why would you want to change the key? Why do you need VBA for creating record instead of data entry on bound form? What data type is ID field? If MachNo is PK, what purpose does ID serve? Why would you want this code adapted to change MachNo? What criteria would need to be met for changing? If you change MachNo PK in parent table then will have to change FK in related tables. Your question lacks detail and is not suited to SO.

Comment: Why would you want to change the key?; I want to change the key Because the vehicle's registration plates may change, so the number in the database must be changed. Why do you need VBA for creating records instead of data entry on a bound form?: Yes, I want to use this method exclusively. f MachNo is PK, what purpose does ID serve?; you can ignore this field.

Comment: I would not use vehicle registration number as PK/FK. As I said, would then have to change every table that uses this value as link. Use autonumber as table link. Then if registration changes, update only one table.

Comment: when I change MachNO I want to update all related records in all related tables as well

Comment: Well, that's no fun and really complicates. If you used autonumber as link then only one table would have to be updated because MachNo would be stored in only one table.